# Taylor series of degenerate rational function

Tags: taylor-expansion, rational-functions

I have a rational function $f$ which is well-defined on $(0, 1]$, degenerate at zero.  I can find the limits as $x \rightarrow 0$ of $f$ and its derivatives, but find that the third and higher derivatives are zero at zero; so the Taylor series around zero is a quadratic.  I find this fact strangely disturbing.  Am I right to feel this way? Are there any structural implications of a rational function having a truncated Taylor expansion at a degenerate point that would indicate I've made an error?

Comment: No, for $x\in \Bbb{R}$, define $P(x)= x^3$, and $Q(x)=x$. Then $f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = x^2$ for $x\neq 0$ (and in fact by defining $f(0)=0$, we can say $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$, so that $f$ is a polynomial). There's nothing wrong with this at all. If you for some reason wish to avoid this "trivial" case, then you should be more specific and impose more restrictions.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo, I feel reassured (I'm not sure why I found this so disturbing)